# can I make a pull request without fork?

Tags: github, pull-request

On Coursera course Version Control with Git, I encountered a problem below:

Which one of these statements is true?

1. A pull request must be made from a forked repository.
2. A pull request can be made only when a branch is being merged.
3. A pull request can act as a form of review and approval.

From my perspective, both 1 and 3 are correct.

Can someone point out which choice is correct, which are incorrect, and provide reasons?

Comment: All three are true for github

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. A pull request can also be made on your own repository by members of that project, so the first choice is not correct.
2. A pull request can also be made between commits, tags, and earlier points in time, so the second choice is not correct.
3. The third point is true. So that's the answer.

Your question is technically about Github, not Git. Git doesn't have pull requests.

Answer (score 0):

Third one statement is true. because we can create pull request without being merged and can be created without fork a repository. And we create a pull request for review the changes first then we're going to merge them into repository for which we created pull request.