# What does it mean that a repo was "Built by" another user in Github?

Tags: git, github

Consider this: account `Aaa` in Github creates a repo called `Aaa/some_repo`.

Now, I'm seeing in `Bbb`'s account that a repo called `Bbb/another_repo` was "*Built by Aaa*".

The `Bbb/another_repo` is not a fork of `Aaa/some_repo` so what does this mean? These two repos do not appear to be linked in any way, so how did `Bbb` created a repo in its account that says "*Built by Aaa*"?

Comment: Can you provide an example link?

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/EPRCCAUNAM) and check under "Created 8 other repositories".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible the [`EPRCCAUNAM/alphalas`](https://github.com/EPRCCAUNAM/alphalas) displays built by xxx, because the latest commit is actually a merge of a pull request initiate by xxx.

[image: Built by]

In that sense, the latest contribution was done:

- either [from the same project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52663255/6309), by [a collaborator](https://github.com/EPRCCAUNAM/alphalas/graphs/contributors),
- or from a fork, whose PR branch has been deleted, as in "[Deleting and restoring branches in a pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/deleting-and-restoring-branches-in-a-pull-request/)" (and even the fork repo could be deleted once the PR is accepted)

Comment: But how does `xxx` initiate a pull request into to other repository when they are not "linked" in any visible way? A far as I can see these two users have no projects in common either (or any project fr that matter).

Comment: @Gabriel You do not have to have a fork to initiate a PR. If you are a collaborator, you can push directly to the *same* repo a new branch, and request a PR from that new branch to master, within the *same* repo.

Comment: By the *same* repo you mean `EPR../alphalas`? Because `xxx` has no access to that repo.

Comment: In that case, maybe it was from a branch of a fork, since then deleted. And `Aaa/some_repo` has nothing to do with that PR.

Comment: I was thinking that something like that may have happened. Thank you.

Comment: @Gabriel I have edited the answer to make that second scenario more visible, and documented with a link.

Answer (score 0):

On GitHub, there's a repository owner whose username appears in the URL to the repository page. The owner can provide access to other individuals, but his/her username remains associated with the repository.

So in your case [here](https://github.com/EPRCCAUNAM):

`EPRCCAUNAM` created the repo, provided access to `iphadra` and `iphadra` did the work, so it shows `"built by iphadra"`

Comment: This does not seem to be the case. If the iphasra user attempts t modify the `EPR../alphalas` repo it says that it does not have permissions to do so and a fork is created.